# Istio Gateways and Selector Issues 1.0.2 -> 1.2.3

Tags: istio

Previous set-up which worked on 1.0.2 Istio:

Istio namespace:

Istio ingress-gateway

Application namespace:

App-gateway with selector for ingress-gateway

App-Virtual-Service with routing rules for application (pointing to app-gateway)

On 1.0.2 this functioned correctly, however upon upgrading to 1.2.3 this only results in 404's from the route not being picked up/registered with the ingress-gateway.

I have tried moving the app-gateway to the istio-system namespace, as there is some conflicting information about the selector requiring to be in the same namespace. (both on it's own and with the virtual service using the FQDN of the app services)

Linking the virtual service directly with the ingress-gateway works as expected, however this isn't the most elegant/organised solution compared to what we had at 1.0.2.

I would expect the application-gateway to register it's virtual-service routes with the ingress-gateway when kept in a different namespace, however you do not seem to be able to use any additional gateways and specify the ingress-gateway with the selector.

Comment: Could you please add the configuration example of what was working in 1.0.2 and isn't working in 1.2.3? Your less elegant workaround configuration would be also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The istio upgrade from version 1.0.2 to 1.2.3 may have caused this problem. According to [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/setup/upgrade/steps/):

> Istio does NOT support skip level upgrades. Only upgrades from 1.2 to 1.3 are supported. If you are on an older version, please upgrade to 1.2 first.

Comment: Link only answers are unacceptable by community standards. Kindly also explain how this solves the OP's problem.